# Ctrl+U in emacs when using evil key bindings

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I'm using the wonderful evil package for vim bindings in emacs.

The one key that is not right is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. It is still the emacs prefix, rather than "up".

Does anybody have a solution for that in some lisp code for my .emacs?

Thanks.

Comment: So, what answer did you end up using?

Comment: See accepted answer: evil-want-C-u-scroll t

Comment: With org-mode and related packages, `C-u` comes with lots of functionalities. But I get you, I want it to be scrolling up. Just curious if anyone knows how and what keybinding should we save the original emacs' `C-u` to?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

there is a variable that you can add to your `.emacs`

```
(setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
```

it needs to appear before the call to `(require 'evil)`.

Comment: What does C-u get replaced with? Or not really needed with evil's args? Some emacs commands behave a bit different with an arg.

Comment: It's pretty key that this is before the (require 'evil)! I put this at the top of my emacs file before loading the package manager.

Comment: This does not seem to work (gnu-emacs 24.3.1) if I am using emacs client (even if server is restarted), https://gist.github.com/vrthra/9999335

Comment: @rahul have you found the solution yet ? I find that it doesn't work for me too

Comment: @nXqd I haven't actually

Comment: @rahul the answer by Shrikant Sharat works for me. You should try that.

Comment: I can confirm this is not working, Kevin Ushey's answer is.

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, it's easy enough to define your own keybindings, and the `evil` API is rich enough to make it super easy:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-u")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (evil-delete (point-at-bol) (point))))
```

I had to go this route as `evil-want-C-u-scroll` wasn't functioning correctly for me.

Comment: Almost perfect... C-u in Vim deletes to the current indent on first press, then deletes the indent on second press.

Answer (score 10):

In order to get [bling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851955/1293385)'s answer to work for anyone useing John Wiegley's [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), make sure you define it in the `:init` section, like so:

```
(use-package evil
 :ensure t
 :init
 (setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
 :config
 (evil-mode 1)
 ;; snip...
)
```

HTH

Answer (score 8):

Vim's `C-u` is half-screen page up. I replicated it using the following,

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
```

From `C-h f evil-scroll-up`,

> (evil-scroll-up COUNT)
>
> Scrolls the window and the cursor COUNT lines upwards.
>   The default is half the screen.

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete - this won't enable C-u in modes other than Normal mode.

Comment: `C-u` already has this behavior in visual mode. In insert mode, in vim, it does't scroll up, it deletes back to start of line/entry into insert. I'm not sure how you'd replicate that behavior in emacs.

Comment: You're right, redefining `C-u` as in the answer also affects Visual mode. I had assumed it wouldn't because `evil-visual-state-map` wasn't updated, but I guess that's unnecessary for some reason.

Comment: I think you assumed correct. Its just that `C-u`'s default behavior in visual mode is already correct. No need to define it.

Comment: I don't think `C-u`'s default behavior is to scroll up in visual mode. I disabled all key mappings and Evil-mode customizations in my `.emacs` and then tried `C-u` in both normal mode and visual mode, and in both cases, it displays `C-u-` in the minibuffer and waits for an argument. And `C-h c C-u` in both cases displays "`C-u` runs the command `universal-argument`". Only after I `M-x eval-expression` and paste in your `define-key` code does `C-u` make the buffer scroll up. I'm running Evil 1.0.1, the latest version.

Comment: Yep, you're right. My `define-key` does set `C-u` in visual mode too. Thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1):

The vim's `C-u` is not 'previous-line, it's more like page up. I don't know how to replicate the exact behavior, but you could just try `C-b` (evil-scroll-page-up) or map `C-k`, `C-j` to go up/down 10 lines.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 10)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") (lambda () (interactive) (next-line 10)))
```

The `C-u` key is also quite important to Emacs so you probably shouldn't overwrite it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [melleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826709/3199242)'s answer, I also defined the key combination when evil-want-C-u-scroll:

```
(use-package evil
:ensure t
:init
(setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)

(when evil-want-C-u-scroll
   (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
   (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
   (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up))

:config
(evil-mode 1)
...
)
```

This works for GNU Emacs 24.4.1

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map  "\C-u" 'previous-line)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map  "\C-u" 'previous-line)
(define-key evil-replace-state-map "\C-u" 'previous-line)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map  "\C-u" 'previous-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-u" 'previous-line)
```

Since I can't really test myself (no evil), try maybe the following if those do not work:

Replace

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-u" 'previous-line)
```

With

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "cu" 'previous-line)
```

Do this for whichever mode of evil you want it/it is neccessary.

Furthermore, maybe there is an "evil" version of `up`, you might want to bind that instead.

Also, correct me if I am wrong, but I am pretty sure evil 'ships' with a functional/useful "up" somewhere in those keybindings, maybe read up on it somewhere.

Comment: I meant "up", not previous line, as in the default vim/less functionality.

Comment: try defining (kbd "C-u") instead of "\C-u" or "cu" or whatelse.